# How do I add constraints to Itertools Product?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to list all products with numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] string length of 4 with some constraints.

- Position 0 must be < 8
- Positions 2 and 3 must be < 6

With the current code it is printing every possible combination so I was wondering how do I go about filtering it?

```
import itertools

number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

result = itertools.product(number, repeat=4)

for item in result:
    print(item)
```

I've tried using `if product[0] < 8 or product[2] < 6 or product[3] < 6:` but I don't know where to fit in or how to format it.

Comment: What do you mean by `Position 0 must be < 8` and `Positions 2 and 3 must be < 6`? Where are you getting 8 and 6 from?

Comment: I want strings like [8 , 8 , 6, 6] / [8, 8, 8 ,7] etc to be excluded.

Comment: Filter before passing to `product` to get the equivalent of: `product('1234567', '12345', '12345', '12345678')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simplify this and avoid wasting a lot of cycles by looking at the inputs carefully.

`repeat=4` means that you want to iterate over the following:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

However, what your question is asking is how to iterate through

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Since the conditions on the inputs are independent (the value of one element is not what restricts the others), you can adjust the inputs instead of filtering elements after the fact.

I suggest you just iterate over the sequences you want directly instead of filtering the output. You don't need to make actual lists: a `range` object will be much more efficient:

```
itertools.product(range(1, 8), range(1, 9), range(1, 6), range(1, 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `and` rather than `or`.

```
for item in result:
    if item[0] < 8 and item[2] < 6 and item[3] < 6:
        print(item)
```

Comment: It's much more efficient to filter **before** generating the `product` than sorting after

Comment: True, if that's possible. It is for `product`, but it doesn't generalize to things like permutations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `and` instead of `or` to get Positions 2 and 3 must be < 6 and Position 0 must be < 8. And put this statement in the for loop `if item[0] < 8 and item[2] < 6 and item[3] < 6:`

so your final code should be:

```
import itertools

number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

result = itertools.product(number, repeat=4)

for item in result:
    if item[0] < 8 and item[2] < 6 and item[3] < 6:
        print(item)
```